# Animating an arc reveal

Tags: animation

I am trying to replicate the arc flying over the logo in [this classic Disney intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayRlrAtnmlY).

How do I achieve this type of animation effect in blender?

Comment: Welcome @Raz, please take the [tour] and read [ask] to help you get the most out of your question.  It is worth that questions should show some research and effort on your part, remembering that you will receive more help when this is the case.

Comment: you could create the full curve and the animate a cube with the boolean modifier  set to Difference to create the reveal. Once you have that then add and animate the lead star. Feel free to edit your question, I suggest a screen shot from the video half way through the arc. and imagine that none of use have seen the Disney intro before when describing your requirements.